# Hive JDBC fails to connect configured schema

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am able to connect to Hive using hive-jdbc client and also using the beeline.Typical url is,

```
jdbc:hive2://hive_thrift_ip:10000/custom_schema;principal=hive/hive_thrift_ip@COMPANY.COM
```

Unfortunately the connection is always established to the 'default' schema of Hive , and it is not considering the configured schema name in the url. I use the org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver class

It always takes me to the tables of the default schema. Still I am able to access the tables from other schema using the schema name prefix to the tables, like custom_schema.test_table

Kindly let me know if I missed any property or configuration in the connection creation part which will help me in getting the session exclusively for the schema that configure in the url.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5904) help you at all?  Your URL syntax seems off to me.